# Is there some fast algorithm to check substrings in two string sets

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

There is two string set (c++)

```
set<string> set1, set2;
```

I need to iterate set1 to check if any string in set1 is substring of string in set2.

Code below is my solution, is there any fast algorithm?

```
for(auto& str1 : set1) {
    for(auto& str2: set2) {
        if (strstr(str2.data(), str1.data()))
           // do something
    }
}
```

There are some restrictions

1. this function is used in online RPC servers
2. candidates of set2 and set1 may be too large to be loaded in memory entirely, so I can't build some index like trie or cache result.

Comment: `strstr(str2.data(), str1.data())` really?

Comment: How long are the strings to be expected? Very long or a few bytes? If `str2.data()`s are long-ish, and `str1.data()` are short-ish, you could [boyer-moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm).

Comment: Have you considered using something like [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [Commentz-Walter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm) that can search for multiple patterns in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

Suffix tree would be faster, `O(n + m)`  where `n` is total length of all strings in set1 and `m` in set2, your set approach would be `O(n*m*min(n,m))` in worst case, suffix array also uses linear memory.

If it does not fit into RAM you can consider splitting it up into "chunks" that fit and then checking all pairs of "chunks" from set1 against set2 and building suffix tree on them.

Also if hardware has SSD, virtual memory is also quite fast nowadays

Answer (score -1):

Since you are interested whether there are any elements matching the criteria, then you could break from the cycle when the first is found. That's one obvious performance optimization.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @Slava this answer contains an idea for optimisation, but thanks for the input.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26980680)

Comment: @coelhudo the question asked for ways to make the algorithm quicker. This answer guides the asker to break from the inner cycle if a match has been found. It is short, but definitely provides a way to improve the performance of the 3D cycle the question is referring to.